# No Success in installing Puma Gem in fedora

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, openssl, puma

I have been trying to install puma gem in my rail apps but it doesn't seem to work. When i try

```
sudo gem install puma
```

i get this : [image: Command Line]

i checked out previous questions which were pertinent, and they mostly suggested configuring openssl for the same. I tracked down my openssl and its locations are :

/usr/share/ruby/openssl, /usr/share/doc/openssl, /usr/share/licenses/openssl, /usr/lib64/openssl, /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl

and tried installing puma, mentioning the directories, just hoping it would work but to no avail. Any help  would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think it's an SSL problem?

Comment: i dont think that it is...i don't understand my problem so to speak.  i looked up and found the solutions. They spoke of mentioning "cpp-flags", followed by the location of openssl in my system.

Comment: It's been a while since I installed Ruby on Linux, but if you had installed Ruby using Linux based package managers, you may have installed some of the packages required to run Ruby coode, but not the ones required to install gems that contain C-based code.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0):

You have committed a sin while installing rails:

> Under no circumstance should you install Ruby, Rubygems or any Ruby-related packages from apt-get. This system is out-dated and leads to major headaches. Avoid it for Ruby-related packages. We do Ruby, we know what's best. Trust us.
>
> -Ryan Bigg

First, uninstall your existing rails and ruby.

Then, follow this blog- [Ubuntu, Ruby, ruby-install, chruby, Rails and You](http://ryanbigg.com/2014/10/ubuntu-ruby-ruby-install-chruby-and-you//). It is for ubuntu but you will be easily be able to adapt it for Fedora.

Also, after you follow the guide, don't use `sudo` to install gems or to run `bundle` commands.